# Ireland Visa Minimum Finances Requirement

Tags: working-visas, ireland, financial

I have received a job offer from a university in Ireland, and I am currently in the process of applying for an Employment (Scientific Researcher) visa for Ireland. One of the required documents is an up-to-date bank statement.

However, the amount of money I have in my bank account is not that much (around USD 4500) and I would like to know if there is a minimum amount of money available in the account before applying, as I do not want my application to be rejected.

Is there a minimum financial requirement for an Employment (Scientific Researcher) visa to Ireland? And if there is, how much is it? Thanks.

Edit: The account I have opened was solely for the purpose of visa application, but for New Zealand, not Ireland. It is about two months old, and the money in it has been put there only once (during the opening). I am not currently employed, as I have just finished my PhD (mid-November), and this would be my first real job. That money was just something I borrowed to some relative while I was a teaching assistant in Auckland, New Zealand.

Comment: Account balances are more relevant for tourist visas than for job visas.  But putting money in the account for no readily documented purpose is far more likely to lead to a rejection than any given balance in the account.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for the comment. The account I have opened was solely for the purpose of visa application, but for New Zealand, not Ireland. It is about two months old, and the money in it has been put there only once (during the opening). I am not currently employed, as I have just finished my PhD (mid-November), and this would be my first real job. That money was just something I borrowed to some relative while I was a teaching assistant in Auckland, New Zealand. How can I explain this to them? This is a good opportunity for me and I don't want to miss it for such a trivial reason.

Comment: I'd frankly be inclined to close the account, repay the loan, and submit in the application that you do not have a bank account.  I don't know much about how Ireland assesses its visa applications, but I expect that it is similar to the UK, and if that is true then they will want to see evidence that you got the money legally, and, if it's a gift or loan that your relative also came by it legally.  They also want to know that the money is yours to spend; if you have to pay it back then they might discount it anyway.

Comment: @phoog I that case one of the application documents will be missing, and my application would likely be rejected altogether, wouldn't it?

Comment: Perhaps.  How are you funding your trip?  Are you planning to use the money in that account?

Comment: @phoog My plan is to use the money in my account to pay for the air ticket and the first month or so of my stay in Ireland, until my first paycheck comes in. I have checked the rent and other living expenses in Cork, and I believe  USD 3000 should be enough for me to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a comment, you wrote

> My plan is to use the money in my account to for the air ticket and the first month or so of my stay in Ireland, until my first paycheck comes in. I have checked the rent and other living expenses in Cork, and I believe USD 3000 should be enough for me to start with.

In that case, you have a cushion of 50% over your budget.  I do not know about the cost of living in Cork, but for a month or so, this seems like an adequate amount to me.  Let's look at the [guide to supporting documentation](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Employment%20Scientific%20Researcher):

> Finances
>
> - You must provide an up-to-date bank statement, showing what money has been paid into and out of the account over the last six months and showing sufficient funds to cover your costs.
> - Bank statements must be on headed paper - internet printouts will not be accepted.
> - Your name, address, account number and account type must be visible on the statement. Any large lodgements must be explained.
> - If you are sending a bank statement from a deposit/savings account, you must also include a letter from your bank confirming that you are allowed to withdraw money from that account.

The first bullet point addresses your question.  There is no explicit balance requirement for the bank account.  The proposition that USD 4,500 is adequate will be stronger if you have a realistic budget prepared that shows expected expenses of around USD 3,000.

The third bullet point is significant, since the source of the money in the account is a single large deposit.  Explaining this deposit probably warrants consultation with an Irish immigration lawyer.  At a minimum, you will probably need a formal written statement from the relative who loaned the money explaining the purpose for which it was loaned to you (i.e., to help you cover your expenses before your first paycheck) and when you are expected to pay it back.

It may also be necessary to include the lender's bank statements showing the outgoing transfer.  These should probably also make it clear that the lender has come by the money legitimately.  The question of whether to include the lender's bank statements is the main reason for my suggestion to talk to an Irish immigration lawyer.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Talking to an Irish immigration lawyer is a great idea. But here in Morocco we do not have an Irish embassy for the moment, only a honorary consul. I will call him as soon as possible and see if he can answer some of these concerns and direct me to an immigration lawyer in case that would be needed.

Comment: @SaïdMaanan unfortunately, most government representatives are unable to give advice of this nature or to recommend specific service providers.  Some consulates and embassies have lists of service providers that they can give you, however, so you might ask.  I would be more inclined to ask the institution that has offered the job whether they have someone they can recommend.

Comment: To add to @phoogs advice, some institutions will be willing to give the first salary payment early to help with setup costs (some will even offer a bonus payment, and reimburse expenses!). You should esquire about this! And definitely ask them if you have any queries with the visa process, since they will have experience sponsoring many hundreds of visa applications.

Comment: @phoog That is also great. The offer I received was from University College Cork, and I think it's a respectable institution, and most likely they will have some guidance for me, as they hire many foreigners and must be familiar with those issues.

Comment: @MJeffryes That is a great idea. I will send them an email once they reopen. Unfortunately, due to Christmas holidays, they will not open until the 14th of January 2019.